# Can anyone give me a solution how we will merge the two different repositories i.e.. two tables in a same database we want to use a Linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Working code - but it is not getting output what is the wrong in this code:

```
            var result =  _favouriteProjectRepository.Entity()
                                                     .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                                                     .Select(x => new FavouriteProject
                                                                  {
                                                                      ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                                                                  }).ToList();    
                        
            var resultset = await _projectrepository.Entity()
                                      .Where(x => (filters.FiscalYear == null ||              
                                                   filters.FiscalYear.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.ContractNo.ToString().Substring(0, 2)))) && 
                                                  (filters.IsFavourite == false && 
                                                   result.Contains(x.Id).ToString()))
                                      .Select(x => new Tests
                                                   {
                                                       Id = x.Id,
                                                       Name = x.Name,
                                                       AdvertisementStatusId = x.AdvertisementStatusId,
                                                       CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
                                                       ContractNo = x.ContractN0,
                                                   })
                                      .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                                      .ToListAsync();
            
            Models:-
             public class FavouriteProject
                {
                    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
                    public string UserId { get; set; }
            
                    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
                }
            public class Tests
                {
                    public int Id { get; set; }
                    public string Name { get; set; }
                    public int? ContractNo { get; set; }
                    public int? AdvertisementStatusId { get; set; }
            
                    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
            
                    public virtual ICollection<FavouriteCompany> FavouriteCompany { get; set; }
            }
            **filters**
        public class ProjectFilters
        {
                    public List<int> FiscalYear { get; set; }
                    public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
        }
            
    **Project Model**
      public class Project
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            public string ProcurmentNo { get; set; }
            public int? ContractNo { get; set; }
            public int? ProjectSizeId { get; set; }
            public int? SelectionProcedureId { get; set; }
            public int? ResponseRequestedId { get; set; }
            public int? AdvertisementStatusId { get; set; }
            public int? NoOfPages { get; set; }
            public string PreQualificationRequirements { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string MultilineDescription { get; set; }
            public string BridgDesignWorkType { get; set; }
            public string DbeMbeRequirements { get; set; }
            public string SpecialNote { get; set; }
            public decimal? BudgetAmount { get; set; }
            public decimal? EstimatedContractAmount { get; set; }
            public decimal? MaxumumContractAmount { get; set; }
            public bool? IsMultipleContracts { get; set; }
            public string ProposedScopeLoc { get; set; }
            public string BondingRequirements { get; set; }
            public string TechQuestionsAddressedTo { get; set; }
            public int Status { get; set; }
            public int? DistrictId { get; set; }
            public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
            public string ResponseEmail { get; set; }
    
            public string ViewRFP { get; set; }
            public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
            public string LowBidDesign { get; set; }
            public string AdminNote { get; set; }
            public string MeetingLocationNotes { get; set; }
            public string FdotKey { get; set; }
            //public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
            public bool IsUpdatesLocked { get; set; }
            public bool? BdiProjectIndicator { get; set; }
            public string LiabilityInsurance { get; set; }
            public string ProjectThreshold { get; set; }
            public int NumberOfContracts { get; set; }
            public int? RelatedProjectCount { get; set; }
    
            public string AdvertisementSpecialNotes { get; set; }
            public string FMNSpecialNotes { get; set; }
    
            public virtual ProjectSize ProjectSize { get; set; }
            public virtual SelectionProcedure SelectionProcedure { get; set; }
            public virtual ResponseRequested ResponseRequested { get; set; }
            public virtual AdvertisementStatus AdvertisementStatus { get; set; }
            public virtual District District { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ProjectEvent> ProjectEvents { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<FinancialManagementNumber> FinancialManagementNumbers { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ProjectWorkGroup> ProjectWorkGroups { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ScrapedLink> ScrapedLinks { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ProjectStandardNote> ProjectStandardNotes { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<FtpFileProject> FtpFileProjects { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<CompanyProject> CompanyProjects { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ContactProject> ContactProjects { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ProjectUnderUtilizedWorkGroup> ProjectUnderUtilizedWorkGroups { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<WorkProgram> WorkPrograms { get; set; }
    
            [NotMapped]
            public virtual ICollection<ScrapedProjectModel> ScrapedProjects { get; set; }
    
           // public virtual FavouriteProject FavouriteProject { get; set; }
```

**Can anyone give me simplified query to call both in single request?
And I have added my models and filters you can go through it I have used only one filters  and the model of project because in that class only I have mentioned**

Comment: `result.Contains(x.Id).ToString()` - has no sense to make it string. Post model classes and filter class.

Comment: But when we are not using Tostring() It is showing an error i.e cannot convert from int to entities.favouriteproject

Comment: it is the filters  public List<int> FiscalYear { get; set; }
        public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }                                                                                                       public class FavouriteProject
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
}

Comment: That's why I ask for filter classes and model classes. I can rewrite this query to be effective. Edit original question and add additional details.

Comment: okay sure I will edit just now

Comment: Please add `Project` model also

Comment: added project model also

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv
One more question in linq how we will use where condition instead of join for example you have joined by using join Is there  any links by using where condition

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query = _projectrepository.Entity().AsQueryable();

if (filters.FiscalYear?.Count > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => filters.FiscalYear.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.ContractNo.ToString().Substring(0, 2))));   
}

if (filters.IsFavourite)
{
    var favouriteProjects =  _favouriteProjectRepository.Entity()
        .Where(x => x.UserId == userId);   

    query = 
        from p in query
        join f in favouriteProjects on p.Id equals f.ProjectId
        select p;
}
                    
var resultset = await query
    .Select(x => new Tests
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        AdvertisementStatusId = x.AdvertisementStatusId,
        CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
        ContractNo = x.ContractN0,
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv
Tq for helping its working

Comment: One more question how we will use where condition instead of using join in linq Is there any links could you provide me in comments -- @Svyatoslav Danyliv